# How do you unlock the Chocobos in Final Fantasy XIII?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I've reached Pulse, and I know there are Chocobos around here somewhere. How can I unlock them?

Comment: I think you mean Final Fantasy XIII?

Comment: fixed the title @146

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Kevin Y said, you need to unlock then beat mission 14 to unlock the chocobos, which requires you to beat 13...this is the chain:

1->2->3->5 and 7->12->13->14. The link has all the location maps for the Bosses+Cieth Stones.

After you beat 14 you will find Chocobos scattered throughout the Archelytte steppes. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete missions 12, 13, and 14.